# Trying to apply array modifier to armature

Tags: modifiers, armature, constraints

I'm trying to create drawers dynamically and place them in a Desk. I have created a drawer instance with an armature, as I want to add some contraints to it to allow it to open only in X certain amount. I'm creating this in a separate blender folder so I can import it as an asset from anywhere. This is the desk: [image]
And I would like to add this drawer's aramatures to be child from the main desk2 armature and add then a constraint to them. [image]

I have tried using array modifiers, but does not work as the modifiers only apply to the mesh, not to the armature so only the drawers are being populated [image]

I have tried to parent the Drawer Armature that contains the mesh from another empty mesh to use instancing, but because the mesh I'm creating is a plane, and it does not have Height, drawers are not being populated vertically.

I would like ideally to reach a solution similar to another desk I built manually [image]

But currently I'm finding it really difficult to do it with array modifers or grid/empty object instancing. Any ideas how this should be done? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, what kind of animation do you plan to create exactly?

Comment: Not planning to add any animation. But when I export that desk asset, I would like to open certain random drawers to fit the scene as I want. Sometimes I might have all the drawers closed, sometimes I would like one to be half opened, that is why I want to add constraints to the bones, so the drawers can only open certain amount. But would like to do this in an automated fashion if possible, so all these bones are added automatically using the array modifier and parented to the main desk bone.

Comment: You could use a Limit Location constraint so that you can easily limit the drawer on X. You can't use the Array modifier because it doesn't create meshes or objects that you can individually manipulate, maybe simply create link-duplicated objects? Parenting each object to a bone would allow you to quickly reset them to their default pose, you could also create a pose library?

Comment: The limit location constraint is not a problem, what I'm wondering is how can I automatically using the array modifier or some other way, to create 3X5 Drawers with their bones and limit constraints linked as a parent to the main desk bone.

Comment: Create a drawer object, link-duplicate it (but it could also be part of the furniture object as a simple mesh), create an armature, align each bone to each drawer...

Comment: I think you're getting confused between the the Object constraint modifier and the Bone constraint modifier. You won't actually need an armature or bones at all if you aren't intending to animate the object.

Comment: I think I need both. I want to add a drawer with a bone with a constraint modifier, so the drawer can be opened or moved from an axis only. That would be simple to do if I only had one drawer, but I have 15. And I don't want to go one by one binding bones to the parent desk bone (I want all the drawers to move if the parent boen is moved) so I thought the array modifier would help. but it is very challenging as well.

Comment: the Array modifier won't help a lot, you can use it if you want but you'll need to apply it at the end, and separate each drawer as separate objects if needed

Comment: I would like to do something like that, but if all the objects that I'm generating would be automatically parenting their drawer armature to the desk base armature would be great. Trying to do much manual work if it can be automated somehow. But using the array modifier doesn't work, as it leaves the drawer armature out, and I need it to open the drawers once I hypotetically be able to apply the modifier.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to do it manually, it won't take long